# Active and inactive checkbox with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am working on Web App with ASP.Net MVC and have a problem with HTML checkbox element.So this is my ViewModel for checkbox's:

```
public class ServiceViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

My View is Like this:

```
        @model IList<Saloon.ViewModels.ServiceViewModel>

        <ul>
             @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
             {
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="@Model.Name[i]" id="@(i+1)" />
                    <label for="@Model.Name[i]">@Model.Name[i]</label>
                </li>
             }
        </ul>
```

and my JQuery code for checked and unchecked the checkbox's:

```
<script>
$('input[type=checkbox].chk').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
</script>
```

but this JQuery code does not work.even I've tried `$('input[type=checkbox].chk').change(function () {...`
and some other ways which available with JQuery and I found on the Internet but those doesn't work too.

Comment: Put the script code in document.ready block, as you need the element present in DOM before you access them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your code is almost there**, but you missed a thing, `document.ready()`

Your code is supposed to work, there's nothing wrong with changing the status of checkboxes.

Instead, your `.click()` won't be properly initilized because jQuery is not fully loaded. Well maybe there's another factor for not firing the events properly, but this is what I can guess from what you provided.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox].chk').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any problem with function I am using with click event?

Comment: @Farid then it's about how you render the script section on your cshtml. It looks like `.net-mvc`. Giving me the related codes like your full `cshtml` that your code belongs to and your `BundleConfig` ( if you are using this ) and if possible, which error you can see on your browser console ( browser console log will be the fastest way to solve this problem, if there's none, it's 100% that your web is not loading your `jQuery` correctly.

Comment: I am implementing my app with asp.net mvc5 and n-layered architectural pattern and also based on Request-Response service.but I am new in JQuery.

Comment: @Farid Getting to know how you render your script is essential to pick up the exact problem and solve this case. Maybe you should use [https://dotnetfiddle.net/](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) This is .NET fiddle for .NET MVC

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the checkbox if it gets checked that means the checked property is now set to true and then you are checking the condition if it is checked set it to unchecked and vice versa which of course will not produce any result. After checking the checked property to true set the checked property to true only and vice versa. In this practical example this wouldn't serve any purpose, because you are not doing any other processing.

Use class name only to do your job.Like the one given below

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.chk').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true );
            } else {
               $(this).prop('checked', false );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```